# how to distribute surplus load of user traffic to google app engine from google compute VM ? running django with apache

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running django on google VM instance using apache and mod wsgi... i however am unsure of the concurrent requests that my app shall receive  from the users and would like to know if i can transfer the surplus load of the VM to the App engine automatically to prevent the server from crashing.

I am unable to find any solution expect running kubernetes cluster or docket containers to effectively manage the load. but in need to be free of this hassle and send off the excess load to GAE.

Comment: The answer to your question is no using Google services. Google does not offer load balancing between Compute Engine and App Engine. If your service runs on App Engine, then use App Engine as it autoscales. Otherwise, use a load balancer and autoscaling with Compute Engine.

Comment: thanx ! wish it could be done in future !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to analyze the traffic, latency and load of your resources and applications, I would recommend you to start with Stackdriver Trace.

As per documentation, [Stackdriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/) is a distributed tracing system that collects latency data from your applications and displays it in the Google Cloud Platform Console. You can track how requests propagate through your application and receive detailed near real-time performance insights. Stackdriver Trace automatically analyzes all of your application's traces to generate in-depth latency reports to surface performance degradations, and can capture traces from all of your VMs, containers, or Google App Engine projects.

Once you have determine the user traffic or you have a better idea about this, then you can try using "[Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/)".

GCE offers two kind of VM instance groups:

- Managed instance groups (MIGs) allow you to operate applications on multiple identical VMs. You can make your workloads scalable and highly available by taking advantage of automated MIG services, including: autoscaling, autohealing, regional (multi-zone) deployment, and auto-updating.
- Unmanaged instance groups allow you to load balance across a fleet of VMs that you manage yourself.